# How can I make a ternary association in staruml

Tags: uml, staruml

I want to make a ternary relationship in staruml 
 [somthing like that[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYNmd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StarUML does not support N-ary (ternary) association. However, [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/) is one of the most powerful tools for UML, and as you asked for, it does also support N-ary associations, as you can see in the following image:

[image: as you can see]
This is a great tool which is much more powerful and even more friendly than StarUML, so in case you're struggling with this tool at some point, there are many tutorials online that can guide you through this, [such as this one](http://www.dpi.ufv.br/projetos/geoprofile/tutorial_visual_english.html).

Good luck with it.